# How to use regular expression to validate wrong symbol

Tags: regex, expression

I'm completely new and have a question. I have an XML parameter form file with field validation like this:

```
ValidChars="(?=.\*[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%*])" ErrorOnValidationFailure="Entered Invalid Char."
```

The current expression `((?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%*]))` can generate an error only if the first char is incorrect. Once I enter a valid character, the validation stops working. Is there a regex that will enable me to identify an invalid character in any part of the string?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us how you are applying the expression to the input. That it is stored as XML is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Try `ValidChars="[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%*]*"` is it is an XML/XSD regex.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that `(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%*])` regex executed once only asserts if the input string contains a character from the specified ranges/sets defined in the character class *after* 0+ characters (in NFA regex, other than a newline/carriage return/etc. - depends on the regex library).

What you need to use is a regex to check if the whole string consists of your whitelisted characters, so you need a

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%*]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM4iA2/1)

The `$` might be replaced with `\Z` in Python, or `\z` in PCRE/.NET regex to disallow trailing newline at the end of the string to be accepted.

If the pattern is used by a method that anchors the pattern by default, you need no `^`, `$`, `\A`, nor `\z`/`\Z`.